# I need to clear my doubts about the repaint() method

Tags: java, swing

So I have been trying to make a pong game using javax.swing and as many of you know that I will need to call the repaint() method in a loop. It works just fine when I put the timer in the class that extends JPanel (Display.class) but when I use another class as a "gameloop" and call it in a loop (with the help of a timer or a thread) it simply doesn.t work I don't know what is going on.

If someone has a different approach on how to do it please let me know (I would prefer if the timer stayed in the Gameloop.class).

And I want to know the EXACT reason on what's causing this behavior so I don't run into the same problem again.

Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here's the code if you wanna review it, the problems are in the "Display" and "Gameloop" classes

```
package pong;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        new Main().start();
        
    }
    
    public void start() {

        new GUI();
        new Gameloop();
        
    }
    
}
```

```
package pong;

import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI extends JFrame {

    GUI() {
        
        setTitle("Pong");
        setSize(600, 400);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
        add(new Display());
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        
    }
    
}
```

```
package pong;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Display extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    int PANEL_WIDTH = 584;
    int PANEL_HEIGHT = 362;
    private int BALL_X;
    private int BALL_Y;
    private int BALL_SIZE;
    private int BALL_X_VELOCITY;
    private int BALL_Y_VELOCITY;
    private int PLAYER_WIDTH;
    private int PLAYER_HEIGHT;
    private int SELF_X;
    private int SELF_Y;
    private int OP_X;
    private int OP_Y;
    boolean gameRunning = true;
    Handler handler;
    
    Display() {
        
        handler = new Handler();
        getConcreteValues();
        
    }
    
    public void getConcreteValues() {
        
        BALL_SIZE = handler.getBallSize();
        PLAYER_WIDTH = handler.getPlayerWidth();
        PLAYER_HEIGHT = handler.getPlayerHeight();
        
    }
    
    public void getVariableValues() {
        
        int[] recievedData = handler.getData();
        BALL_X = recievedData[0];
        BALL_Y = recievedData[1];
        BALL_X_VELOCITY = recievedData[2];
        BALL_Y_VELOCITY = recievedData[3];
        SELF_X = recievedData[4];
        SELF_Y = recievedData[5];
        OP_X = recievedData[6];
        OP_Y = recievedData[7];
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        
        super.paintComponent(g);
        
        g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, PANEL_WIDTH, PANEL_HEIGHT);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillOval(BALL_X, BALL_Y, BALL_SIZE, BALL_SIZE);
        g.fillRect(SELF_X, SELF_Y, PLAYER_WIDTH, PLAYER_HEIGHT);
        g.fillRect(OP_X, OP_Y, PLAYER_WIDTH, PLAYER_HEIGHT);
        
    }
    
}
```

```
package pong;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Handler {
    
    private int BALL_X = 100;
    private int BALL_Y = 100;
    private int BALL_SIZE = 15;
    private int BALL_X_VELOCITY = 5;
    private int BALL_Y_VELOCITY;
    private int PLAYER_WIDTH = 8;
    private int PLAYER_HEIGHT = 70;
    private int SELF_X;
    private int SELF_Y;
    private int OP_X;
    private int OP_Y;
    
    private PrintWriter writer;
    private BufferedReader reader;
    
    public void setUpConnection(String SERVER_IP, int PORT) {
        
        try(Socket socket = new Socket(SERVER_IP, PORT)) {
            
            writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            System.out.println("Network established!");
            
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            
            System.out.println("Failed, try again later");
            ex.printStackTrace();
            
        }
        
    }
    
    public int[] getData() {
        
        BALL_X+=BALL_X_VELOCITY;
        
        int[] data = {BALL_X, BALL_Y, BALL_X_VELOCITY, BALL_Y_VELOCITY, SELF_X, SELF_Y, OP_X, OP_Y};
        
        return data;
        
    }
    
    public int getBallSize() {
        return BALL_SIZE;
    }
    
    public int getPlayerWidth() {
        return PLAYER_WIDTH;
    }
    
    public int getPlayerHeight() {
        return PLAYER_HEIGHT;
    }

}
```

```
package pong;

import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Gameloop implements Runnable {
    
    Thread t;
    Display display;
    Handler handler;
    
    Gameloop() {
        
        display = new Display();
        handler = new Handler();
        
        try {
            t = new Thread(this);
            t.start();
        } catch(Exception ex) { }
        
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        
        display.getVariableValues();
        display.repaint();
        
    }

}
```

I hope this is all the info you will need.

I don't expect (or ask) anybody to just solve my problem but I want a detailed explanation as to why this behavior is happening.

And yes I also tried using Timer in java.swing to execute the gameloop as well and it still didn't work

Comment: There's no loop in your gameloop.

Comment: additionally to previous comment, `new Display()` being added to the frame is not the same as `new Display()` used in the loop -- the loop is calling `repaint()` from an instance that is not the one being displayed -- solution: create only one single instance of `Display`

Comment: Didn't see that coming, it was a silly mistake and thank you so much

Comment: You create an instance of Display in GameLoop AND GUI - they are disconnected, so when calling repaint on the instance created in GameLoop, it’s not the instance thats displayed on the screen - see “dependency injection” for a solution

Answer (score 1):

The instance of `Display` you create here...

```
Gameloop() {
    display = new Display();
    handler = new Handler();
    
    try {
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    } catch(Exception ex) { }        
}
```

has nothing to do with the instance you create here...

```
GUI() {        
    setTitle("Pong");
    setSize(600, 400);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    add(new Display());
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);        
}
```

so, calling `repaint` on the instance of `Display` in the `GameLoop` will have no effect, as it's not actually displayed on the screen.

Instead, you should be passing the same instance of `Display` to both `GUI` and `GameLoop` ... although I'd be making use of `interface`s to do this, as `GameLoop` should be doing NOTHING else to the component.

This is a concept known as [Dependency Injection](https://medium.com/groupon-eng/dependency-injection-in-java-9e9438aa55ae)

This...

```
@Override
public void run() {
    display.getVariableValues();
    display.repaint();
}
```

is some what pointless.  As it's only going to execute once and then exit (and the associated thread will be terminated).

Instead, you should be setting up some kind of loop which will continue to run (until you request it to stop via some kind of flag).  This is pretty basic socket handling.

You should also consider either making a `protected` inner class that implements `Runnable` or make use of anonymous class instead, for example...

```
t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do you game loop logic here
        // or call a protected method to do it
    }
});
```

Implementing the `run` interface will expose the `public` `run` method, and realistically, no one else should be calling `run`

`setSize(600, 400);` and `int PANEL_WIDTH = 584;`/`int PANEL_HEIGHT = 362;` are bad ideas.

A window's viewable area is it's size minus it's decoration insets, this will  always make the viewable area smaller then the actual window size.

Instead, the components should report their `preferredSize` and then the window should be `pack`ed around it.

I can tell you straight up, on my system, those values are going to produce some very bad results.

For example...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        new Main().start();
    }

    public void start() throws InterruptedException {
        Display display = new Display();
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        new GUI(display);
        new Gameloop(display, handler);

    }

    public class GUI extends JFrame {

        GUI(Display display) {

            setTitle("Pong");
            //setSize(600, 400);
            //setResizable(false);
            //setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
            add(display);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            pack();
            setVisible(true);

        }

    }

    public class Display extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        int PANEL_WIDTH = 600;
        int PANEL_HEIGHT = 400;
        private int BALL_X;
        private int BALL_Y;
        private int BALL_SIZE;
        private int BALL_X_VELOCITY;
        private int BALL_Y_VELOCITY;
        private int PLAYER_WIDTH;
        private int PLAYER_HEIGHT;
        private int SELF_X;
        private int SELF_Y;
        private int OP_X;
        private int OP_Y;
        boolean gameRunning = true;
        Handler handler;

        Display() {
            handler = new Handler();
            getConcreteValues();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(PANEL_WIDTH, PANEL_HEIGHT);
        }

        public void getConcreteValues() {
            BALL_SIZE = handler.getBallSize();
            PLAYER_WIDTH = handler.getPlayerWidth();
            PLAYER_HEIGHT = handler.getPlayerHeight();
        }

        public void getVariableValues() {
            int[] recievedData = handler.getData();
            BALL_X = recievedData[0];
            BALL_Y = recievedData[1];
            BALL_X_VELOCITY = recievedData[2];
            BALL_Y_VELOCITY = recievedData[3];
            SELF_X = recievedData[4];
            SELF_Y = recievedData[5];
            OP_X = recievedData[6];
            OP_Y = recievedData[7];

        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            super.paintComponent(g);

            g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, PANEL_WIDTH, PANEL_HEIGHT);
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillOval(BALL_X, BALL_Y, BALL_SIZE, BALL_SIZE);
            g.fillRect(SELF_X, SELF_Y, PLAYER_WIDTH, PLAYER_HEIGHT);
            g.fillRect(OP_X, OP_Y, PLAYER_WIDTH, PLAYER_HEIGHT);

        }
    }

    public class Handler {

        private int BALL_X = 100;
        private int BALL_Y = 100;
        private int BALL_SIZE = 15;
        private int BALL_X_VELOCITY = 5;
        private int BALL_Y_VELOCITY;
        private int PLAYER_WIDTH = 8;
        private int PLAYER_HEIGHT = 70;
        private int SELF_X;
        private int SELF_Y;
        private int OP_X;
        private int OP_Y;

        private PrintWriter writer;
        private BufferedReader reader;

        public void setUpConnection(String SERVER_IP, int PORT) {

            try (Socket socket = new Socket(SERVER_IP, PORT)) {

                writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                System.out.println("Network established!");

            } catch (Exception ex) {

                System.out.println("Failed, try again later");
                ex.printStackTrace();

            }

        }

        public int[] getData() {

            BALL_X += BALL_X_VELOCITY;

            int[] data = {BALL_X, BALL_Y, BALL_X_VELOCITY, BALL_Y_VELOCITY, SELF_X, SELF_Y, OP_X, OP_Y};

            return data;

        }

        public int getBallSize() {
            return BALL_SIZE;
        }

        public int getPlayerWidth() {
            return PLAYER_WIDTH;
        }

        public int getPlayerHeight() {
            return PLAYER_HEIGHT;
        }
    }

    public class Gameloop implements Runnable {

        Thread t;
        Display display;
        Handler handler;

        public Gameloop(Display display, Handler handler) throws InterruptedException {
            this.display = display;
            this.handler = handler;
            t = new Thread(this);
            t.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            display.getVariableValues();
            display.repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

This...

```
public void getVariableValues() {
    int[] recievedData = handler.getData();
    BALL_X = recievedData[0];
    BALL_Y = recievedData[1];
    BALL_X_VELOCITY = recievedData[2];
    BALL_Y_VELOCITY = recievedData[3];
    SELF_X = recievedData[4];
    SELF_Y = recievedData[5];
    OP_X = recievedData[6];
    OP_Y = recievedData[7];
}
```

is problematic.  Swing is NOT thread safe (and is single threaded).  This means that you should not be modifying the UI or any state the UI relies on from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  It also means that you shouldn't be performing long running or blocking operations on the Event Dispatching Thread either.

See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more details.

You've, instead, used a `Thread` to poll a `Socket` for data, which is read in the above method, and then which updates state information used by the UI.

This can lead to dirty reads (data is not updated correctly across the thread contexts) and/or dirty paints.

There is also a potential for long and variable delays between the reads, which would cause the paint pass to also be delayed.

So, what's the solution?  Well, that's a more difficult answer.

I would first, have a clock which ticked at a regular interval and repainted the component.  As you seem to have done the past, this could be simply implemented by a Swing `Timer`.

I would then have a `SwingWorker` read the data from the `Socket` and `publish` the results, which would then be `process`ed safely within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  In order to facilitate this, I would wrap this information in some kind of object.

At this point, this information would be synced back to the UI via the "main game loop", but in your case that would probably just mean taking the latest response and updating the "remote player" information on the `Display`.

Realistically, you should have a `Player` class, you'd then pass two instances to `Display`, one representing the local player and one representing the remote player.

Your game loop would then be required to process local events and update the local player (possibly submitting those updates to the other party) and updating the remote player instance with the events from the other party.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a while loop like so ->

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while(t!=null) {
         display.getVariableValues();
         display.repaint();
    }
}
```

Also your `GUI` class uses one instance of Display, while your `Gameloop` class uses another one. Maybe remove the constructor from your `Main` class and change the `GUI` constructor to this instead ->

```
  GUI() {
        
        setTitle("Pong");
        setSize(600, 400);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
        Display display = new Display();
        add(display);
        new Gameloop(display);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        
    }
```

Change your `Gameloop` class to use this `Display` passed by GUI

```
 Gameloop(Display display) {
        
        this.display = display;
        handler = new Handler();
        
        try {
            t = new Thread(this);
            t.start();
        } catch(Exception ex) { }
        
    }
```